# Selecting specific columns to according to last row value by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Please i need your support to Select specific columns to according to last row value by VBA

in order to paste this selection only

as i'm working on a project and only what i can do is that select the entire exist data to the last row and copy it normally but there are some columns that i do not want to select them

Any Help Please!
This code select the entire data
Imported1ws.Range("A2:C" & Imported1LastRow).Copy destination

but actually for example i need to copy only A2:to its last row, C2:to its last row, F to its last row
also how could i paste this selection to my destination

Comment: If each column has a different last row, then you need to loop.

Comment: Please note that All column are with the same last row so any help!

Comment: Then you still need to loop, or if you want the columns to be pasted side by side, you can build up a range address: `...Range("A2:A" & Imported1LastRow & ",C2:C" & Imported1LastRow & ",F2:F" & Imported1LastRow)`.

Comment: Please include your code that copies the entire data and a list of the columns you want to copy to the destination worksheet, instead. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66165835/edit) your post at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy Non-Adjacent Columns

- [`Application.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)
- [`Range.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy)
- Adjust `"A:A,C:C,F:F"`, `"Sheet1"`, `"A"` (source last-row-column), `"2:"` (source first row), `"Sheet2"`, `"A2"` (destination first cell).

**A Common Scenario**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyNonAdjacentColumns()
    ' Constants
    Const sCols As String = "A:A,C:C,F:F"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sLastRow As Long
    sLastRow = sws.Range("A" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = Intersect(sws.Range(sCols), sws.Rows("2:" & sLastRow))
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("A2")
    ' Copy
    srg.Copy dCell ' A,C,F to A,B,C
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much VBasic2008, It worked as for me :) really i appreciate your help :)